# XSLT transformation in memory using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xmldocument

Good afternoon all,

I dont know why this is proving so difficult but I must be having one of those days!

I am trying to perform and XslCompiledTransform on an in memory XmlDocument (I have retrieved the XML from a webservice and saved to a database) object. I have the following code so far:

```
        string xslFile = "C:\\MOJLogViewer\\GetClaimTransformed.xslt";

        XslCompiledTransform processor = new XslCompiledTransform();
        processor.Load(xslFile);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        processor.Transform(xdoc.CreateNavigator(), null, ms);

        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);

        XmlDocument transformedDoc = new XmlDocument();
        transformedDoc.Load(reader.ReadToEnd());


        string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ms.Close();
```

When I try to run this code I get the "illegal characters in path" exception. The path does not contain any of the illegal characters so I am absolutely stumped!

I hope you can help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a different localization for Windows OS and english  localization for VisualStudio?

Comment: What's the type of xdoc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
transformedDoc.Load(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

`Load` reads from a path; you probably want `transformedDoc.LoadXml(...)`. But in all honesty, you could just write the whole thing to a `StringWriter` - more direct:

```
string output;
using(var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    processor.Transform(xdoc.CreateNavigator(), null, writer);
    output = writer.ToString();
}
```

Plus it will work for non-xml outputs (xslt is not obliged to output xml).

Comment: Thank you very much - my head is simply not working today! Once again, thanks

Comment: Odd. On the `Transform` call, I get `XslTransformException: White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead.`  Who knows why it can't strip whitespace, nor why it needs to.