# Work with XML file that is recieved from AWS (Amazon webservice)

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-web-services

I have a button on my Form in C# , when a user clicks on it an XML file received from AWS (Amazon WebService). I want to process this received XML file with xml stylesheet. Should I save this XML in local and then work with that? Or what is the best solution for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your xml from response stream in XDocument and create XPathNavigator object in-memory. Then you could use overloaded Transform() method to perform stylesheet applying in-memory too.
Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966266/xslt-transformation-in-memory-using-c-sharp)